# ChangeListener JButton Issue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to create buttons that change the color of an object when they are pressed. However the object changes color whenever my mouse merely hovers over the button. Am I using the wrong listener? I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
blue.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
            object.setColor(color.blue);
            objectIcon.repaint();
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use an [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) on the button.

E.g.

```
 blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            object.setColor(color.blue);
            objectIcon.repaint();
        }
    });
```